# BasicResponseHandler() get response body encoding with utf-8 when content-type not explicit

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x

The server part didn't explicit a content-type with encoding information such as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. And it seemed that when there isn't a explicit encoding info in the response header. `BasicResponseHandler()` just can't **handle** that. I mean it gives a result like

```
"nickname":"çæå¥","sex":1,"language":"zh_CN"
```

with `System.out.println`. Here `çæå¥` was expected to be a Chinese character.

```
public class TestResponse {
    public static void main(String[] argvs) throws IOException {

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/userinfo?access_token=OezXcEiiBSKSxW0eoylIeGw-AUf2G2djwCnNpRDH83rrLz6HNf-VUOXvPnQ9GLk2bhW-gRNPl6KuqdpbG5sJ93e9xwetzkIuP");
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        System.out.println(handler.handleResponse(httpResponse));
    }
}
```

So is there anyway to do that other than implement the `ResponseHandler` interface myself?